# how to open image library of Android device

Tags: java, android, camera

in my app i am using an Camera for an operation. i am able to open camera and i can work on it, but before opening the camera i want to have an option named Album. When i select this i want view the image stored in the android device so far that too in a grid view.

how to perform this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access an image from the phone's photo gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144783/how-to-access-an-image-from-the-phones-photo-gallery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am right what you want is to open up the gallery and view the images in it in a grid view. If this is what you are looking for following is a piece of code to do this.

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Write the above code in the click event of the "Album" button.Above code will open up the gallery and displays the images in default grid view. Hope this helps you.