# How to access an image from the phone's photo gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

By any chance, does anyone know how to access the phone's photo gallery?
I am making an application that takes a picture of a plant leaf and
analyzes the image to determine whether or not it is determine. We were hoping that we
could give the user two options of taking the picture of the leaf or using an image of a
leaf that the user has already taken. However, we got the picture taking part, but we do not
know how to access the photo gallery.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to launch the Gallery App using the built-in `Intents`. After that, on your `onActivityResult()`, get the path of the selected image and load your image into your `ImageView`

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
<Button
 android:id="@+id/loadimage"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Load Image"
 />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/targeturi"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/targetimage"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity

```
 package com.exercise.AndroidSelectImage;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AndroidSelectImage extends Activity {

    TextView textTargetUri;
    ImageView targetImage;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);
         textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);
         targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

         buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
     }});
     }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     Uri targetUri = data.getData();
     textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
     Bitmap bitmap;
     try {
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
      targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
    }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Do not forget to add the following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Im trying to put the uploaded image as a background do you know how?

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is only needed if you don't already have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Are you sure that MANAGE_DOCUMENTS makes sense? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html says: "This permission should only be requested by the platform document management app. This permission cannot be granted to third-party apps."