# How to use pictures from the phone in android memory game

Tags: java, android

I am making a small application for my daughter (in android) where I want to use some of the pictures from the phone as pictures for the memory cards.

As far as I know the pictures that can be used are the ones in the resource folder so I am basically looking for some suggestions as to use pictures outside the resource folder (in the application)???

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144783/how-to-access-an-image-from-the-phones-photo-gallery

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have looked (and understood) the link tha thou sent me, but somehow I run into an issue because; when I am loading the images into a list (reference to the images that are to be used in the memory game) the references are all integers (refs to ints) but the resource used in the example from the link is a bitmap). 

My question now is how to convert the bitmap into something that could be used in the list - or maybe my question is intact, should I used something else than a list of int references to be able to use the bitmap as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission for this inside the manifest file

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```