# Image processing android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I am in the process of developing an android application within Java in order to process images. The application will compute mean squared error and structural similarity difference in order to group similar images together.

My question is, I am looking to be able to import images from the phones gallery into a SQLite database which will then be called upon within the application. Is there any way in which I can access the phones gallery from within my application?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144783/how-to-access-an-image-from-the-phones-photo-gallery

Answer (score 1):

to begin try this query and save the result. Getting all the images from gallery at once can take time, so try upon request.

```
db.rawQuery('SELECT imageBlob FROM Images WHERE imageID=?', new String[] {imageID});
```